# Telegram bot run_repeating with python-telegram-bot library

Tags: python, datetime, telegram-bot

I'm just starting to discover how to build a bot with python.
I'm trying to send a message at certain time. Seems that the **callback_minute** function won't accept more than one arguments.I read a lot of example, I read the documentation regarding **run_repeating** function but I can't fix this issue...

my target is to get the **chat_id** dinamically. Someone can help me?

```
import logging
import sys
import requests
import random
import datetime

import telegram.ext
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, Filters, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler, CallbackContext

from lib import utils


class MonoBot:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

    # define a command callback function
    def start(self, update, context):
        #a = utils.search(self, update.message.from_user)
        #context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=update.message.text + a)
        update.message.reply_text("write /lista top know what u can do...")

    def echo(self, update, context):
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=update.message.text + " stuff")

    def option(self, update, context):
        button = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton("text 1", callback_data="1")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("text 2", callback_data="2")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("text 3", callback_data="3")],
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button)
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="scegli..", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    def button(self, update, context):
        query = update.callback_query
        # context.bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat_id, text="vitto " + query.data)
        # use this below in order to hide option
        context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id, text="vitto " + query.data,
                                      message_id=query.message.message_id)

    def get_location(self, update, context):
        button = [[KeyboardButton("share location", request_location=True)]]
        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(button)
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="share location?", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    def location(self, update, context):
        lat = update.message.location.latitude
        lon = update.message.location.longitude
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="lat:" + str(lat) + " lon:" + str(lon),
                                 reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    #conversazione
    def cancel(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        print(update.message.from_user)
        update.message.reply_text("by by :)", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        return ConversationHandler.END

    def cerca(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        print("-"*40)
        print(update.message.text)
        word = update.message.text.split(" ")[1]
        print("-"*40)
        update.message.reply_text('https://www.google.com/search?q='+ word)
        #return ConversationHandler.END

    def lista(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        update.message.reply_text("qua metto l\'elenco dei comandi che espongo...tipo\n- /cercaGOOGLE\n- /altrocomando")
        print("-" * 40)
        print(update.message)
        print("-" * 40)
        return CERCA

    def reply(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        user_input = update.message.text
        update.message.reply_text(utils.search(self, user_input))
        #return ConversationHandler.END

    # i'm trying to send a message at certain time...
    def callback_minute(self, update, context):
        #-1001198785547
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="tempoooooo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = MonoBot()
    # first of all take token in order to authenticate
    # check new messages --> polling
    updater = Updater(token=sys.argv[1])
    # allows to register handler --> command, text, video, audio, ...
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    # CORE <<-----------
    # create a command headler and command heandler to dispatcher ###ORDER LIST IS IMPORTANT!!
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', bot.start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('option', bot.option))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('location', bot.get_location))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location, bot.location))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(bot.button))

    #updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, bot.reply))

    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    word, cmd, LOCATION, CERCA = range(4)
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('lista', bot.lista)],
        states={
            CERCA: [MessageHandler(filters=Filters.text, callback=bot.reply)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('exit', bot.cancel)],
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)


    # from here time issue..
    j = updater.job_queue

    j.run_repeating(bot.callback_minute, interval=60, first=10)
    #t = datetime.time(6, 15, 00, 000000)
    #j.run_daily(bot.timer, t, days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), context=None, name=None)

    #updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, bot.echo))
    # start polling
    updater.start_polling()
    #updater.idle()  # ???
```

I get below error:

```
2021-02-15 22:21:04,527 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - DEBUG - Setting singleton dispatcher as <telegram.ext.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at 0x7f8719922040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vitto/PycharmProjects/monopattino/mono_bot.py", line 118, in <module>
    j.run_repeating(bot.callback_minute, interval=60, first=10)
  File "/home/vitto/PycharmProjects/monopattino/mono_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/jobqueue.py", line 291, in run_repeating
    j = self.scheduler.add_job(
  File "/home/vitto/PycharmProjects/monopattino/mono_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 434, in add_job
    job = Job(self, **job_kwargs)
  File "/home/vitto/PycharmProjects/monopattino/mono_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._modify(id=id or uuid4().hex, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vitto/PycharmProjects/monopattino/mono_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 180, in _modify
    check_callable_args(func, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/vitto/PycharmProjects/monopattino/mono_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 401, in check_callable_args
    raise ValueError('The following arguments have not been supplied: %s' %
ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: context
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `update` from `callback_minute()` like this:

```
def callback_minute(self, context):
    #-1001198785547
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        text='tempoooooo'
    )
```

There is no `update` delivered when executing a job.

Comment: Please improve your answer with using correct upper case letters and break your code lines at 80th char